# Datatables - Jquery - MVC

Tags: datatables

I'm using data tables for datagrid on ASP.Net MVC but getting following error, need help, my code is below:

DataTables warning: table id=hatchery-certificates - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Thanks In advance!

Comment: This just means that your HTTP endpoint isn't returning a "200 Success" message.  You will need add a minimal code example that shows the error to this question as your error is most likely an unhandled exception in your server side code.

Comment: Thanks for the hint you provided!!

Answer (score 1):

You should have to return **Json** format from the back end side in the response where you calling ajax in datatable then its fine. Other than **Json** return type it will displaying this type of error.